# Basics Android UI design issue

Tags: android, layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:background="@layout/roundedshape"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"> 

    <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100px" />

    <LinearLayout android:gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/gallerytext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView android:text="TextView"
            android:id="@+id/taskname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gallerytext"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_left"
            android:layout_width="27px"
            android:layout_height="27px"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Add"
            android:id="@+id/button_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Edit"
            android:id="@+id/button_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_right"
            android:layout_width="27px"
            android:layout_height="27px"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edited

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="200px" android:background="@layout/roundedshape"> 

<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100px"
/>

<TextView android:layout_below="@+id/gallery" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/taskname" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

<Button android:id="@+id/button_left" android:layout_below="@+id/taskname" android:layout_width="27px" android:layout_height="27px" ></Button>
<Button android:text="Add" android:id="@+id/button_add" android:layout_below="@+id/taskname" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_left" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<Button android:text="Edit" android:id="@+id/button_edit" android:layout_below="@+id/taskname" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_add" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/button_right" android:layout_below="@+id/taskname" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_edit" android:layout_width="27px" android:layout_height="27px"></Button>
```

When I put a background for the `RelativeLayout` it covers the two `LinerLayouts`.

How can I have the background color and the two `LinearLayout`s visible on top? Or is my perception wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your layout.  If you set the background of the **RelativeLayout** to `#FFFFFFFF` (white) then that's exactly what happens.  The background (including where the **LinearLayouts** are) turns to white.  But the **LinearLayouts** are on top of the **RelativeLayout** - you still see the buttons and any text displayed from within the **LinearLayouts**.  If you set the background of the **LinearLayouts** to different colours you'll see this reflected in the layout - they are effectively on top of the **RelativeLayout**.

Answer (score 0):

you are not wrong 
because relative layout is the father class in this layout file so relative layour's background covers both child class background by default.

if you want custom background in linear layout so write in linear layout tag

```
android:background = "#000000"
```

or

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
```